# SimplePie issue with getting content from Google News feed

Tags: rss, simplepie, google-news

I am using SimplePie to get the feeds from Google News. I am however observing that the img sources are not being fetched correctly.

Here's what the description in the original feed looks like:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;"><tr><td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNFxFgqMWvxBxPVu6p-aU3v0pJu2gQ&amp;url=http://www.usnews.com/news/newsgram/articles/2013/09/13/flash-floods-force-thousands-of-evacuations-in-colorado"><img src="//t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSxoCFv79Ha0yUykBX1dB_2DZ4EKcS1ZNeqvOH1iadwNXYcCt24RarH73QM2SLhZlDneouYmLcD" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" /><br /><font size="-2">U.S. News & World Report</font></a></font></td><td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br /><div style="padding-top:0.8em;"><img alt="" height="1" width="1" /></div><div class="lh"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGd4g82yHYtsE0yKm-BARxQXUnssg&amp;url=http://www.mercurynews.com/nation-world/ci_24094661/ap-photos-colorado-deals-more-flooding"><b>AP PHOTOS: Colorado deals with more flooding</b></a><br /><font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">San Jose Mercury News</font></b></font><br /><font size="-1">Floodwaters are forcing thousands more people from their homes in Colorado. The National Guard is helping to rescue residents of neighborhoods and even whole towns that have been cut off. Rain continues to fall up and down Colorado&#39;s Front Range,&nbsp;<b>...</b></font><br /><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNFArY6FkAQxRE9YP6l-azKNO1iZeA&amp;url=http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/09/14/us-usa-colorado-flooding-idUSBRE98B0KM20130914">Four dead in Colorado floods amid rescues, scenes of devastation</a><font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f"><nobr>Reuters</nobr></font></font><br /><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNHdlGhiWaxAwUEVPx2V0o77pZdnWA&amp;url=http://www.chron.com/news/us/article/Rescues-accelerate-as-floodwater-inundates-Colo-4813883.php">Rescues accelerate as floodwater inundates Colo.</a><font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f"><nobr>Houston Chronicle</nobr></font></font><br /><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNEpW5-a736KDTVpiTw8DS2i8f_gfw&amp;url=http://www.cnn.com/2013/09/13/us/flooding-colorado/">Heavy rainfall heading once more for flooded Colorado</a><font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f"><nobr>CNN</nobr></font></font><br /><font size="-1" class="p"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGhIXRkmwvTwW5hVoNCZxjDaK8Wdg&amp;url=http://www.thenews.com.pk/article-118176-Death-toll-in-Colorado-floods-rises-to-four"><nobr>The News International</nobr></a>&nbsp;-<a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNEmNdnRbeTxET3GWNqqKGaI2e9eEw&amp;url=http://www.10news.com/news/u-s-world/death-toll-in-colorado-flooding-rises-091313"><nobr>10News</nobr></a>&nbsp;-<a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNH4odpx1qNQYFtgxbaCMgFskkar1A&amp;url=http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/four-dead-in-colorado-flooding-as-rescues-continue/article14323282/"><nobr>The Globe and Mail</nobr></a></font><br /><font class="p" size="-1"><a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=dRXgHRvQFLpiYIMXE3z1jdW26VD6M&amp;ned=us&amp;topic=h"><nobr><b>all 953 news articles&nbsp;&raquo;</b></nobr></a></font></div></font></td></tr></table>
```

and here's what I get after using the get_content() function of SimplePie (within WordPress):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top"><tr><td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNH6yMD4i4Z29E-a5pnCJABNh-imJg&amp;url=http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/syria-crisis-assad-hails-russia-kerry-lavrov-meet-in-geneva/articleshow/22523223.cms"><img src="ANd9GcTBJT8599lXjtRn0lsQcpNFcRd0H8esIPIV0E-OEwF5uEw6twsOaE9gLtgn8alWjnwc4PPf1FE" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" /><br /><font size="-2">Economic Times</font></a></font></td><td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br /><div style="padding-top:0.8em"><img alt="" height="1" width="1" /></div><div class="lh"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGP7Ak9kkqVdBKmpFzo-iz7xm27Bg&amp;url=http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-202_162-57602924/united-nations-syria-chemical-weapons-report-overwhelming-secretary-general-ban-ki-moon-says/"><b>United Nations&#039; Syria chemical weapons report &quot;overwhelming,&quot; Secretary <b>...</b></b></a><br /><font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">CBS News</font></b></font><br /><font size="-1">UNITED NATIONS U.N. Secretary-General Ban Ki-moon said Friday that a report on last month&#039;s deadly attack in Syria would be &quot;overwhelming&quot; in showing that chemical weapons were used. 14 Photos&nbsp;<b>...</b></font><br /><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNFRryVPzxNR_K6g9y4Ihy5p6ls1BQ&amp;url=http://www.cnn.com/2013/09/13/world/meast/syria-developments/index.html">Syrian crisis: Keeping up with key developments</a><font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">CNN</font></font><br /><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNFuUVmADgAGmgqmc1LKevOra1zbZw&amp;url=http://zeenews.india.com/news/world/us-accepts-un-will-not-back-force-against-syria_876462.html">US accepts UN will not back force against Syria</a><font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">Zee News</font></font><br /><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGBEM3ADXJdAL0XL74-J76zeysnvg&amp;url=http://www.thenews.com.pk/article-118174-UNs-Ban-skeptical-Assad-will-keep-chemical-arms-deal">UN&#039;s Ban skeptical Assad will keep chemical arms deal</a><font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f">The News International</font></font><br /><font size="-1" class="p"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGaoHs-BUuimgbRrNxIedmDA1JP9A&amp;url=http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/syria/10308480/Assad-guilty-of-crimes-against-humanity-says-UN-chief-Ban-Ki-Moon.html">Telegraph.co.uk</a>&nbsp;-<a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNEs1nxUxWa6BP2UNNWi3lODAtfjfA&amp;url=http://english.alarabiya.net/en/views/news/middle-east/2013/09/14/Putin-moves-closer-to-eliminating-Assad.html">Al-Arabiya</a>&nbsp;-<a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;usg=AFQjCNGdAI1TapX_nojcSv2Xkm22pV9L9A&amp;url=http://www.brecorder.com/top-news/1-front-top-news/135810-us-timeframe-for-syria-chemical-weapons-handover-unrealistic.html">Business Recorder</a></font><br /><font class="p" size="-1"><a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=dHjVOIFjtfIh08MV1HNNn-dBPzhhM&amp;ned=us&amp;topic=h"><b>all 9,730 news articles&nbsp;&raquo;</b></a></font></div></font></td></tr></table>
```

Specifically, we are looking at the difference in the image source:

Original:

```
<img src="//t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSxoCFv79Ha0yUykBX1dB_2DZ4EKcS1ZNeqvOH1iadwNXYcCt24RarH73QM2SLhZlDneouYmLcD" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" />
```

and imported:

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: At first glance it looks like the `:` character in the img src is the issue - at least you're getting everything after it.

Comment: Right but what can be done about it?

Comment: What's the source feed URL?

Comment: http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&output=rss